# Height calculation script gives false results because of Cached HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching

Here is a script I made...

Basically it makes sure a div is at least as high as the viewport when there is no content..
The problem I am facing is when I clicking around my main navigation, because of caching (I presume?), contentHeight is miscalculated (the previous value is kept). When I hit F5 the script works correctly. How can I solve this?

```
(function ($) {
      Drupal.behaviors.backgroundExpand = {
        attach: function bgExpand (context, settings) {
          // Calculate the height of the div we want to apply the background on,
          // the distance of our backgroud div from the top of the viewport,
          // the height of the viewport, the footer and Vo branding bottom bar.
          var contentHeight = $(".content-background-canvas").outerHeight();
          var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
          var votopHeight = $("#vo-top").height();
          var headerHeight = $("header").height();
          var footerHeight = $("footer").height();
          var vobottomHeight = $("#vo-bottom").height();
          // Only if our content is shorter than the viewport height,
          // make it as high as the viewport, minus the values we calculated
          // above.
          if (contentHeight < viewportHeight) {
            jQuery(".content-background-canvas").height(viewportHeight - votopHeight - headerHeight - footerHeight - vobottomHeight);
          } else {
            // Do nothing.
            return false;
          }
          // Bind the Resize event to our function so that the height is
          // recalculated on resize.
          $(window).bind("onload sliderLoaded resize", bgExpand);
        }
      }
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger it:

```
$(window).bind("ready sliderLoaded resize", bgExpand).resize();
//----trigger it at the end----------------------------^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: ohh! yep i see that but instead of `onload` you can use `ready` see the updated one.